# Blazor do something after X-amount idle time

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am fairly new to blazor and core for that matter.

My issue is that i have an API Centric App that will make a login call to an api and get a JWT token. I need to find a way to log the user out after a period of Idle time and clear the JWT token which i am saving.

I read somewhere that they never added a way to detect idle time in Blazor but i am curious if anyone has a solution for this.

Comment: What flavor of Blazor is this for ?

Comment: currently using server flavor not web assembly, i have it kinda working for authentication so if the token is no longer valid, but as i can see there is no place to check this so it will always load that page then flick back to login page if its not valid. As for an idle timer been looking but i'm out of ideas.

Comment: Decide what actions you consider to be signs of activity - do not use mouse movement or keypress, but instead use logical actions in your application, such as "user changed a value", "user navigated", "content was loaded" - and use those logical application actions to reset an idle timeout. Do not use specific input devices (mouse/keyboard etc) unless that is a specific requirement of your application (e.g. how semi-autonomous cars require user interaction on the steering wheel specifically to make sure a human is in control)

Answer (score -1):

Using JavaScript onmousemove and onkeypress events to trigger the Timer function in a Razor component can identify whether a user is active or inactive. If the user has not performed any onmousemove or onkeypress events, the user is considered in an inactive state and the Timer function is called after certain TimeInterval to [perform any action that you want to do.

1. Open _Host.cshtml and update it as below. Call the onmousemove and onkeypress properties in a JavaScript
   function to fire the Timer function in the Razor component.

```html
<body>
     // . . .
     <script>
         function timeOutCall(dotnethelper) {
             document.onmousemove = resetTimeDelay;
             document.onkeypress = resetTimeDelay;
  
             function resetTimeDelay() {
                 dotnethelper.invokeMethodAsync("TimerInterval");
             }
         }
     </script>
 </body>
```

2. Now open MainLayout.razor and call the Timer method to identify whether the user is active or not. You can add your code in the method when user is found inactive

```
@using System.Timers
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
  
 // . . .
 @code {
     private Timer timerObj;
  
     protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
     {
         // Set the Timer delay.
         timerObj = new Timer(7000);
         timerObj.Elapsed += UpdateTimer;
         timerObj.AutoReset = false;
         // Identify whether the user is active or inactive using onmousemove and onkeypress in JS function.
         await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("timeOutCall", DotNetObjectReference.Create(this));
     }
  
     [JSInvokable]
     public void TimerInterval()
     {
         // Resetting the Timer if the user in active state.
         timerObj.Stop();
         // Call the TimeInterval to logout when the user is inactive.
         timerObj.Start();
     }
  
     private void UpdateTimer(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
     {
         InvokeAsync(async() => {

             // ======> DO WHATEVER YOU WANT TO DO HERE <======

         });
     }
 }
```

Comment: Using unfiltered mouse events is just a bad idea - not only for the volume of calls it generates, but also because the immense number of users who do not use a mouse.

Comment: You mean those events won't capture things such as touch input @MisterMagoo?

Comment: I mean keyboard warriors wont be timed out the same way mouse matadors will

Comment: @mister-magoo, could you elaborate how would mouse events be filtered for this purpose?